# Need to find latest timestamp about the customer record which spans across multiple tables

Tags: sql, db2

I have customer records span across multiple tables. and each tables have updated datetimestamp column.

For example :
Customer table - has basic information like name,username,dob,..
Address table - work address, home address
Phones table ,Features table , etc..

so when address is getting updated/added other tables records are not updated.

Here I need to find when a particular customer has got updated, It could be address alone , phones data alone.. like that..

my sql need to provide me - the latest updated datetimestamp for the given customer.

I was checking by joining all these table and used Max(update datetimestamp column of each table)..

but at the end of it , I need only the latest date..

Could you provide me the sql which would help achieving this ?

Note : This is for DB2.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What you want returned is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a select on the date for each table and union the results together. Then you can take the max of this column in the union. The date columns don't need to have the same name, but they need to be the same datatype.

```
Select Max(X.date) 
From (

Select last_update_date as "date" from customer
Union 
 Select last_record_date from customer_transactions
 Union 
 ... select date on as many more tables as needed ...
 ) as X
```

Instead of union, most sql databases also have a "union all" which keeps duplicates and runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
--if you want the table name with the max timestamp

select * from 
(
select 'TABLE1' as TABLENAME, MAX(datetimestampcolumn) as datetimestampcolumn  from TABLE1
union all
select 'TABLE2' as TABLENAME, MAX(datetimestampcolumn) as datetimestampcolumn  from TABLE2
union all
select 'TABLE3' as TABLENAME, MAX(datetimestampcolumn) as datetimestampcolumn  from TABLE3
) tmp
order by datetimestampcolumn desc
fetch first rows only


--If not necessary to know the table name

select max(datetimestampcolumn) as datetimestampcolumn
from 
(
select datetimestampcolumn from TABLE1
union all
select datetimestampcolumn from TABLE2
union all
select datetimestampcolumn from TABLE3
) tmp
```